# Plugin Hook: Get posts

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, hooks, actions

I am building a WP plugin. It shows several featured post images with titles atop. It will have a spot on the admin bar to tell it what the featured posts are. What hook do I use to get the post's image and title?

Comment: Just use get_posts() http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?>

<?php get_post_image($post->ID,'large'); ?>
```

You can customize these to your liking.

or just go to http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts